# uiautomatorviewer - Please export ANDROID_SWT to point to the folder containing swt.jar for your platform

Tags: android, terminal, appium, ui-automation

I am trying to open uiautomationviewer, but whenever I open it gives me this error. I tried to export ANDROID_SWT to this path with this command in the terminal:

export ANDROID_SWT=/Users/stefanjosimovski/Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib/x86_64

But it gives me the same error again.
Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you!

```
Last login: Tue Aug 23 14:27:21 on ttys001
stefanjosimovski@StefanJosimovskis-MacBook-Pro ~ % /Users/stefanjosimovski/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/uiautomatorviewer ; exit;
SWT folder '/Users/stefanjosimovski/Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib/aarch64' does not exist.
Please export ANDROID_SWT to point to the folder containing swt.jar for your platform.

Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

Comment: I also experienced the same issue. Installing https://github.com/appium/appium-inspector
is giving the same ability without using uiautomationviewer.
hope it helps